# "Show block on specific pages" drupal can tokens be used?

Tags: drupal, token

I want to limit a block to only being on the a users account page.  In the section "Show block on specific pages" I used users/[user-name]  (did not work) then I tried users/[user-id]  (did not work).

Are tokens allowed here?  Is there a way to do this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP to get the result you want. I dont know if tokens are allowed here. If you have PHP filter enabled you may use the following:

```
<?php
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1)){
    return True;
}else{
    return False;
}
?>
```

Get the current user with global $user, than get the url arguments with `arg()`:

The first argument should be "user", so `arg(0) == 'user'`.

The second should be the current user uid, so `arg(1) == $user->uid`.

Everything else returns false.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the * wildcard in place of a token. So you would have:

```
users/*
```

Comment: That does not give me the desired effect.  I want to show the page only for the current logged in user.

Comment: Update I only want to display a "block" for the current user.

Comment: @Jim: do you mean that the block's content should be different depending on the user?  Because the "current user" can technically be any authenticated user in which case you can set the block by roles (authenticated user) instead of by path.

Comment: Not exactly. When looking at your own account page I want this to display with your information.  If someone else is viewing your home page then I do not want it to display at all.